# How to program excel file to gather checkboxed documents from list?

Tags: excel, list, vba, checkbox, external

First of all, thank you for good quality of information you are sharing. I appreciate all the questions and answers, which I have found very useful. Now I'm having a problem with vba programming in excel.

I have a long list of different documents and document names/codes in excel, of which I would like to make possible to choose with checkboxes, which documents will be printed.
Documents are already in same word-file, which could be used as a source-file. Therefore checkboxes, document codes and sources should be linked together.
I have created two command buttons next to the list, where one is for printing and creating combined report, the other is for resetting (unchecking all checked boxes).

I hope i made myself clear what I'm looking for and if it's possible to get advices how to go forward.

So far i managed to program the reset button but in order to create printing function i found it really difficult and unclear.

EDIT:

So far I've been trying to create some macro which gathers all the checkboxed lines from the list to another sheet (PRINT) and i started it with following unfinished code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

   Dim cb As CheckBox
   Dim rng As Range
   Dim row As Range

   Set rng = Range(A7, b153)

   For Each row In rng.Rows
      If cb = True Then Run (sbcopyrangetoanothersheet)
   Else: Next row

End Sub

Sub sbcopyrangetoanothersheet()

   Sheets(Documents).Range(A7,b153).Copy Destination:=Sheets(PRINT).Range(A7,B153)

   Range(A7, b153).Copy
   Range(A7, b153).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

Resetting macro:

```
Sub Reset()

Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In Sheets
        On Error Resume Next
            sh.CheckBoxes.Value = False
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next sh

End Sub
```

Comment: Please share the code which is being used to loop through the document. Questions without code are frowned upon.

Comment: Sorry for not marking the code correctly above and thank you for your advice!

Comment: welcome to SO, remember to mark questions as answered if they do, and also remember to upvote any other answers/questions that are helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you!
Do you think this is not possible to make with VBA? I believe in this case, starting completely new programs (with low/no experience) will take a lot more time and effort.

Comment: There is code below that should work for you. Its VBA code. The only thing you need to supply is the path to the word document.

Comment: I've got a lot of help already and i appreciate it. I'm wondering if its possible to program excel to copy speficic ranges or pages into a new one? Templates are all the same, only content changes and each document has a different discipline id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop like this, and print by opening a worddoc and print it through winWord. 
There are allot of options around this so check out the documentation on MSDN but this should point you in a direction.

I do not recommend using VBA for this anymore but rather use .net (vb or c#) winform and openXML to print.

Anywho. here is the code, its ripped from my mind so it might not quite compile.

```
For Each control In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
  If control.Name Like "CheckBox*" Then 
     if control.Object.Value == true then PrintWinWord ("somehow infer word doc Path from eitherName of checkbox or id")
  End If
Next control


Sub PrintWinWord(dim wordDocPath as string)
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(wordDocPath )
    objDoc.PrintOut
    objDoc.Close
    objWord.Quit
End Sub
```